# read database through sql without admin login

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem every time two or more users are connecting to my app.
This is my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "my password";
$dbname="my dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully".'<br>';
if($_SESSION["connected"] == 1) 
  {echo "you are logged in";}
else { die("Please log in to access this page");
  echo "not logged in";}
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Messages</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `mesaje` where reciever='all' order by data desc";
      $result = $conn->query($sql); 
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        {
            if($row["sender"]==$_SESSION["username"])
                echo '<div style="background-color:blue;" align="right">';
            else echo '<div style="background-color:black;" align="left">';
            echo '<p style="color:white;">'.$row["mesaj"]."</p></div>";

      } }}

  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

When I am the only user connected, there is no problem, everything is alright.

**when 2 or more users connect, they receive this error**:

> WARNING: mysqli_construct():MySQL server has gone away

I think that this is because they are more users logged in with the same admin account (maybe I am wrong)
Is there any way to connect to the database and only read it using sql without admin login? Or any other solution to the problem, please!
I am new to SQL

[image]

Comment: What does this query show ? sql> show variables like 'max_connections';

Comment: @Andreas the problem not in query but in connection line

Answer (score 0):

The status report that you get on your phone would make me think, that the server can't handle the second login. What are you hosting it on?
If you think that it's because the two admins, then try create a guest login and connect your user to the db with that.
If all doesn't help, create a login system, that adds a little table with users and so on.

Comment: I am using 000Webhost as hosting service